# Porting Asyncrun vimscript to lua

Tags: vimscript-lua

In my Vim's configuration file `init.vim` I am using code, that sets a default viewer for practically any kind of file suffix. Here I will demonstrate only an example for `.md` files:

```
let g:netrw_browsex_viewer="-"

function! NFH_md(f)
    call asyncrun#run("", "cwd", "typora " . a:f)
endfunction
```

First paragraph makes sure to choose the function based on suffix of the file (*"URI under cursor"*). Second paragraph shows a function whose name i.e. `NFH_md` implies that this is the function opened when `.md` file is in the *"URI under the cursor"*. Inside this function there is an call that opens an external program `typora` asynchronously so that I am still able to continue using Vim.

> If you want to know more use `:help netrw_browsex_viewer`.

I tried porting the mentioned Vim script to Neovim & Lua but I only managed to port first line:

```
vim.g.netrw_browsex_viewer="-"
```

For I don't know, how to properly port the second paragraph. This is why for now I just use Vimscript source code like this:

```
vim.api.nvim_exec(
    [[
        function! NFH_md(f)
            call asyncrun#run("", "cwd", "marktext " . a:f)
        endfunction
    ]],
    false
)
```

But I would love to translate all the code to Lua - Could anyone help a bit to translate this remaining Vimscript code to Lua?

Comment: First paragraph is probably `vim.g.netrw_browsex_viewer="-" but what about second paragraph?
`

Comment: why? What problem are you trying to solve? Just use it.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt If I just use the second paragraph as it is, it crashes the entire `init.lua` script...

Comment: If it truly crashes, it might be a bug. If it just throws some error, the script could be wrong